# Centering left aligned Bootstrap columns with cards inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center a set of Bootstrap cards that are aligned to the left.

I need to have the container div center into the main grid and then have the cards aligned to the left.

I have tried to use "justify-content-center" in the main row but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="  background-color: #999;" >
  <div class="row">
      <div class=col-1></div>
      <div class=col-10>
        
            <div class="container-fluid mt-4" style="  background-color: #ff0;" >
                <div class="row justify-content-left">
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 
                      <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                   
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        
      </div>
      
     <div class=col-1></div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Gozaro/hq6y0z8m/36/

Here is what I get as a result:

[image]

Here is what I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: In your code you have `<div class="row justify-content-left">` change to `<div class="row justify-content-center">` - here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5y02rw3j/

Comment: Thanks but what I need is to have the whole set of cards centered and in the same time justify boxes to the left. Like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AblH.png

Answer (score 0):

updated code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .card{margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                            of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I looking is to have all the cards aligned to the left but the whole group centered, with your solution the last card is centered when the viewport is in a certain size.

Comment: I have edit the post and change the sample images to make more clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user2675966 I have updated the code, and you can add more cards to test if you want.

Comment: Thanks! : ) 
It keeps happening the same if you make the viewport wider you will see that the whole set aligns to the left. what I'm looking is center-left like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AblH.png

Comment: Thanks again. We are closer, what I see now is that the cards are responsive and I need to have fixed width cards: style="width: 18rem;"

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you want is grid to be centered and cards to left align in the column.

so just add the following **CSS** to row:

```
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

and replace your **HTML** line:

```
<div class="row justify-content-left">
```

With with this:

```
<div class="row col-centered">
```

And to left align card add **CSS**:

```
.card {
    float: left;
 }
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um1sgv60/) to view the result of my answer:

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I looking for I need to have the whole group centered to the blue div, like in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AblH.png

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea base in the code of Jeetan and I found a solution using media queries which I know is the best solution but works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid" style="  background-color: #999;" >
  <div class="row">
      <div class=col-1></div>
      <div class=col-10>

            <div class="container mt-4" style="  background-color: #ff0;" >
                <div class="row justify-content-left">
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 250px;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>



      </div>

     <div class=col-1></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Gozaro/xw786kL0/

The solution is fix the width of the container depending of the viewport width.